# Can we resize the image logo?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-logo

I went to the site settings and updated via look and feel, the sharepoint logo and now I can see that although my logo has size of 160*80px yet it appears small. When I switch back to the SharePoint logo, then, the logo appears bigger in width.

Pls guide on solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OOTB logo is 180px x 64px so I think your image should have those proportions to be shown in best possible way (like the OOTB logo).

So you have to crop your image to the same ratio as the OOTB image.

To modify the rendering to suite your logo format you would have to override at least the `.ms-siteicon-img` css class

This class today applies

```
display:block;
max-height: 64px;
max-width: 180px;
```

which is the cause of your image not being rendered as you wnat

Comment: yes that worked.

Comment: why is it that sharepoint doesnot take the size if different from 180*64.. exmaple:200*80

Comment: Because of the css-class they have adden. I do not know why but I guess it is to not mess up the styles to much if users add very high, or wide images

Comment: Hi Robert, Suppose I want to force SharePoint to show the image with dimensions as 400*180, then, can I do some changes to CSS to achieve this, please guide.

Comment: I have already given you the CSS class in my answer, as well as the properties you need to override (by specificity, !important or by making sure your CSS loads after SharePoints)

Comment: Yes, OK, thanks. Also this link was very helpful http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94687/how-to-make-logo-size-bigger-in-sp2013

Comment: Yep, there you have the whole deal of how to change the rendering so it looks nice