# How to make logo size bigger in SP2013?

Tags: site-logo, size

I am using sharepoint 2013. I  have changed the default logo from the site settings. Now I see SharePoint has resized my logo and it is to small. I would like to make it bigger. What do I need to do to make it bigger? I try add this css below to my custom css, but didnt help. The logo is now bigger, but the left quick launch menu and the first top webpart zone are overriding my logo.

```
.ms-siteicon-img {

max-width: none !important;

max-height: none !important;

width: 308px !important;

height: 154px !important;

}


 .ms-siteicon-a {

max-width: none !important;

max-height: none !important;

width: 308px !important;

height: 154px !important;


}
```

[image]

Comment: did you try to play around with jQuery to move the div in a better place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you change the CSS for siteIcon's image, you have to adjust few other CSS too.

```
div#s4-titlerow {
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
}

div#siteIcon {
    height: 154px;
    line-height: 154px;
    min-width: 308px;
}

div#titleAreaBox {
    margin: 5px 20px;
}

a.ms-siteicon-a {
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 154px;
    max-width: 308px;
}

a.ms-siteicon-a > img {
    height: 154px;
    width: 308px;
}
```