# After making logo bigger. top drop down wont fully open

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-logo

I followed the instructions in the link [Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94687/how-to-make-logo-size-bigger-in-sp2013) but now my top menu which drops down to show all of my departments wont show all of them.(picture shown).Its like it stops at the edge of the content now instead of just going over it.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried increasing the z-index of the menu through css?

Comment: Try removing the 'overflow: hidden' from the div. Open your favorite console editor (firebug or IE dev tool) and play with CSS. It could be either height, z-index or overflow.

Comment: Removing the overflow:hidden worked